# How to get read data in tables from mysql to shiny

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, rmysql

I'm trying to build a shiny app. I've 3 tables in a database. The app will retrieve data tables from MySQL and pop on a web interface. In ui function all the choices are mentioned. When retrieving data from my MySQL, I've written readtable command 3 times. Is there any option to retrieve data from one readtable statement?

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for dataset viewer application
ui<-fluidPage(

  # Application title.
  titlePanel("More Widgets"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:", 
                  choices = c("table1", "table2","table3")),

      numericInput("obs", "Number of observations to view:", 10),

      submitButton("Update View")
    ),

    mainPanel(

      h4("Observations"),
      tableOutput("view")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to summarize and view the 
# selected dataset
server<-function(input, output) {

    conn <- dbConnect(drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),dbname = "xxx",host = "localhost",
    username = "root",password = "yyy")
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
    table1<- dbReadTable(conn = conn,  name = 'table1', value = as.data.frame(table1))
    table2<- dbReadTable(conn = conn,  name = 'table2', value = as.data.frame(table2))
    table3<- dbReadTable(conn = conn,  name = 'table3', value = as.data.frame(table3))

  # Return the requested dataset
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "table1" = table1,
           "table2" = table2,
        "table3" = table3
           )
  })

  # Show the first "n" observations
  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput(), n = input$obs)
  })
        on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for()` function might work:

```
data <- c('table1', 'table2', 'table3')

list_data <- list()

for(i in 1:length(data)) {list_data[i] <- dbReadTable(conn = conn,  name = data[i], value = as.data.frame(table1))}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tables aren't very big, you could opt for an easier solution, namely, replacing output$view with the following

```
output$view <- renderTable({
     head(dbReadTable(conn = conn,  name = input$dataset), n = input$obs)
})
```

This code doesn't cache the tables as your code does, but is much simpler. However, if the tables in the database aren't very big the performance penalty will be small.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone. Joris Gillis, thanks a lot for your help. It's working the way I want using your piece of code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use input$dataset instead of manually writing the name of the dataset in  dbReadTable statement.

Note: It will work fine if the rows in the table are approx 30,000.

Hope this helps.